# Demographics, particulary age distribution in Wuhan and Hubei province

Tags: demographics, population, china, covid19

Are demographic data, specifically age distribution available for Wuhan and the Chinese Hubei province?

I would like to know if the age distribution is somewhat comparable with other urban areas across the globe.

In particular I suspect that if migrant workers from surrounding rural areas  left their child in the care of grandparents, coupled with the one-child policy, the proportion of children would be smaller then in comparable urban areas elsewhere.